# How to get wkhtmltopdf to properly encode Ω?

Tags: c#, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to convert the following HTML to PDF. How can I get wkhtmltopdf to encode the Ω symbol?

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Front door1</td>
    <td>Fire Exit 2</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>Non EOL</td>
    <td>-</td>

    <td>0Ω</td>
</tr>
```

but the rendered PDF is appearing with the 0Ω as:

[image]

This is how I'm converting the HTML to PDF:

```
using (var htmlStream = GenerateStreamFromString(renderedText))
{
    try
    {
        using (var pdfStream = new FileStream(_fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            Printer.GeneratePdf(htmlStream, pdfStream);
        }
    }
}


    public static Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
    {
        UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        string unicodeString = s;
        byte[] encodedBytes = utf8.GetBytes(unicodeString);
        var encodedHtmlString = utf8.GetString(encodedBytes);

        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

        writer.Write(encodedHtmlString);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
    }
```

Where GeneratePDF is defined as:

```
public static void GeneratePdf(Stream html, Stream pdf)
{
    Process process;
    StreamWriter stdin;
    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();

    psi.FileName = "path/to/wkhtmltopdf.exe"

    psi.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(psi.FileName);

    // run the conversion utility
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardError = true;

    psi.Arguments = "-q -n --disable-smart-shrinking - -";

    process = Process.Start(psi);

    try
    {
        stdin = process.StandardInput;
        stdin.AutoFlush = true;

        stdin.Write(new StreamReader(html).ReadToEnd());
        stdin.Dispose();

        process.StandardOutput.BaseStream.CopyTo(pdf);

        process.StandardOutput.Close();
        pdf.Position = 0;

        process.WaitForExit(10000);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        process.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `wkhtmltopdf` is just a browser under the hood, you can use any [HTML entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/sgml/entities.html) to properly encode special characters:

```
<td>0&Omega;</td>
```